# getting current location longitude and latitude in android

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude, locationmanager

THis is my location class with this i am getting location longitude and latitude, but my problem is if i change my current location the longitude and latitude values are not updating.

if i store my home location in my device, then my app is taking every time the same longitude and latitude values it is not taking my current location details. ex: I was in new york today and I launched a app and the location was my home in new jersey.

```
public class GetLocation extends Activity {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;
    Context mContext;
    Double Longitude, Latitude;
    String NetworkErrmsg = "", GpsErrmsg = "", ProviderErrmsg = "", NoNetworkmsg = "", GpsSuccesmsg = "", NetworkSuccesmsg = "";
    public GetLocation(Context mContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
   public void getLocationDetails() {
      locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 100, new MyLocationListener());
        boolean gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!gps_enabled) {
            GpsErrmsg = "No Gps Connectivity";
        } else {
            showCurrentLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            GpsSuccesmsg = "Gps Enabled";
        }
        if (network_enabled && !gps_enabled) {
            showCurrentLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            NetworkSuccesmsg = "Network Provider Enabled. Please Enable your GPS settings to get exact onaround you list";
        }
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            NoNetworkmsg = "Please Enable your Network/GPS settings to get onaround you list";
        }
    }
    protected void showCurrentLocation(String provider) {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            Longitude = location.getLongitude
            Latitude = location.getLatitude();
        } else {
            NoNetworkmsg = "Please Enable your Network/GPS settings to get onaround you list";
            Longitude=null; Latitude=null;
        }
    }
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
            System.out.println("Longitude " + location.getLongitude());
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            // Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this, "Provider status changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            // Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this, "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            // Toast.makeText(GetLocation.this, "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class GPSLocationBased extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationbased);


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new Mylocationlistener();





    // ---Get the status of GPS---
    boolean isGPS = lm
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // If GPS is not enable then it will be on
    if(!isGPS)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
        intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
         sendBroadcast(intent);


    }

    //<--registers the current activity to be notified periodically by the named provider. Periodically,
    //the supplied LocationListener will be called with the current Location or with status updates.-->
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
}

/**
 *Mylocationlistener class will give the current GPS location 
 *with the help of Location Listener interface 
 */
private class Mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            // ---Get current location latitude, longitude, altitude & speed ---

            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            float speed = location.getSpeed();
            double altitude = location.getAltitude();
            Toast.makeText(GPSLocationBased.this,"Latitude = "+
                    location.getLatitude() + "" +"Longitude = "+ location.getLongitude()+"Altitude = "+altitude+"Speed = "+speed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think in my location class i am not checking location in onLocationChanged method.. is that my mistake?. If i call getLocationDetails() method in onlocaitonchanged method does it work for me?